# Can background-color be used if background gradient is not supported?

Tags: html, css, webkit, gradient

How could i define a background color for devices that do NOT support gradients ?

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #3498db, #1e82b9, #0b6d97, #025877, #034359);
}
```

Comment: just define a background-color at the top

Comment: can you not just put the background color declaration above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `background-color` as fallback, see snippet:

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #3498db, #1e82b9, #0b6d97, #025877, #034359);
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: to be clear, this is not a fallback since both property aren't the same ... the background color will always be there under the image

Comment: I agree. As mentioned above, there are other fallbacks for older browsers, but in practice, this will display a background-color if the gradient isn't supported.